# Bootstrap prevent fluidity on smaller than 800px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have a Bootstrap website and I want that after a certain screen-size, the user to be forced to scroll the broswer.

For example, if I have a the following:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want that after the window is resized below 800px, those div with col-xs-6 to remain at the same width as col-md-6. So the **user is going to be forced to scroll the window.**

I tried to use:

- `min-width` on container (not working, the col-md`s inside the container are still getting the value from window percentages)
- `modifying` the bootstrap.css so that col-xs-6 has exactly 50% of 800px.

None of the above works well. Any advice on how to do that?

Comment: Why would you want this? Google will even find your website not responsive, and will get you a lower rating for that.

Comment: @DannyvanHolten You're assuming that it's a live website and he cares about ratings :P Tbh, there's reasons why people would want to disable responsiveness beyond a certain point. They're few and far between, but they exist. CrazyDog, take a look at this section of Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive It might help you with what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width:800){
   .col-sm-6, .col-xs-6{
        Min-width:50%;
     }
 }
</style>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `min-width:400px;`?